# what is the python equivalent function in ros for rate.expectedCycleTime().toSec()

Tags: python, c++, ros

I am trying to convert a c++ equivalent of a ros program to python.
The current node has a snippet

```
autotune::oscillation_times.at(autotune::oscillation_count) =
            loopRate.expectedCycleTime().toSec() * i
```

How do i convert this to the python equivalent? I am not able to find the documentation for the equivalent module in rospy

Answer (score 1):

according to the [docs of timer.py](https://github.com/strawlab/ros_comm/blob/master/clients/rospy/src/rospy/timer.py#L59):

```
Rate.sleep_dur
```

sample code:

```
hz = 1  # freq
r = rospy.Rate(hz)
expected_cyclic_time = r.sleep_dur
```